# At what radius from the center of a black hole is space infinitely warped?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light

I read that at the singularity point at the center of a black hole, space is infinitely warped. However, how is space not infinitely warped already at the Schwartzchild radius, since at that radius, the escape velocity is equal to the speed of light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Warping" generally means "the amount of curvature at a point".  One can compute the curvature of a black hole spacetime using the rules of Riemannian geometry, and will find the result that all components of the curvature tensor are finite at the horizon (if the metric is in non-singular coordinates).

And the reason why the escape velocity at the horizon of a Schwarzschild black hole is the speed of light is because the curvature is such that the radial direction is slowly rotated toward the time direction as you get closer to the horizon.  At the horizon, it becomes exactly lightlike, and the schwarzschild time coordinate becomes lightlike as well.  But one can just as easily choose  a coordinate system that counteracts this rotation, which will remove the pathology at the horizon.  This is exactly what the "Kruskal coordinates" are.

Comment: Removed some comments. A friendly reminder to everyone- if someone is being rude or otherwise abusing comments, please just disengage and flag them for moderator attention.

Comment: Thanks. How should I understand "lightlike"?

Comment: @LukeHutchison: all paths in spacetime fall into one of three categories: "spacelike", "timelike"  and "lightlike".  You can think of "spacelike" curves as normal geometric curves and "timelike" curves as the paths of observers through spacetime.  Lightlike curves are the border point between the two, and represent the paths of light rays.  In the theory of special and general relativity, this distinction helps to explain why the motion of light is "special" versus the paths of normal physical objects with mass.